# No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml

Tags: python, ros, moveit

I have run the moveit setup wizard on the `j2n6s200_standalone.urdf` file from `https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros`

No errors and all config files were generated.

Unfortunately, when I try to run my mover.py script I get this warning

> Loading robot model 'j2n6s200'...
>
> [ WARN] [1628332445.370599694]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!`

and an error:

```
[ERROR] [1628332450.391446]: Error processing request: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (5s)
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n',
 '  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 632, in _handle_request\n
        response = convert_return_to_response(self.handler(request), self.response_class)\n',
 '  File "/home/spud/catkin_ws/src/kinova_arm/scripts/mover.py", line 76, in plan_pick_and_place\n
        move_group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander(group_name)\n',
 '  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/moveit_commander/move_group.py", line 66, in __init__\n
        self._g = _moveit_move_group_interface.MoveGroupInterface(\n',
 "RuntimeError: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (5s)\n"
]
```

This script is used from a different robot arm, but the group name is the same ('arm')

I assume the robot is not loading correctly, but I'm not sure why or where it is trying to load it from.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide more info on how you launch the robot bringup itself, but according to the README.md in https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros there is a tag `use_urdf:=`. I quote from the page

> use_urdf specifies whether the kinematic solution is provided by the URDF model. This is recommended and is the default option.

so perhaps, if not already, you should be launching the bringup as `roslaunch kinova_bringup kinova_robot.launch kinova_robotType:=j2n6s300 use_urdf:=true`

Hope this helps, if not, I can try to look into it deeper!